# Retina vs Regular Image Resolution : 1 high rez for both or 2 images w/ respective rez for each?

Tags: ios, documentation, retina-display

Any seasoned developer has come to this point in the development cycle: graphics and imaging. Yes, the retina displays are great! But they have certainly caused a lot of commotion among developers (and their designers). Now the question that seems to persist with no good answer is:

*"When designing for both retina and regular displays, do we need to create one image for each resolution, or can we create one image at Retina that scales to both?"*

I read many answers that advocate either sides and 2 times out of 3 they advocate for producing an image for both resolutions. *I personally believe* that you should design one for retina, and use it for both (of course with UD UX testing on lower resolution devices to make sure what was designed for higher rez is suitable on lower). I stand by this because when I design an app with imagery created for retina resolution, is it successfully scaled down to normal rez on devices that don't support retina display? (I did use IB.. I don't know if that has something to do w/it or not..)

But if you are one that advocates for producing an image for both resolutions, take this:

Say for instance you agree that every resolution size needs to have it's own image (with proper file naming convention of course "@2x" "~ipad" etc..) and your app in this instance is a universal app. Wouldn't this mean that for every image, you would need really 4 images? And wouldn't this add significantly to the app bundle size?

Is it possible that providing every image size (w/ proper naming convention) is not a requirement, but merely a possibility?

What is the real answer to this debate?

**Can anyone find a link to *official* apple documentation regarding this issue?**

Comment: See [Can’t I just design at 2× and bitmap scale down to 1×?](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eli, I posted this same question to the Quartz list (or participated in a discussion there) on this exact topic, but I cannot seem to find it just now.

The overwhelming consensus there was to product two images. While using just @2x images does appear to work, the flash footprint was viewed as of little performance compared to:

- the OS has to use more horsepower to render the images, affecting performance
- memory consumption goes up by 4x on devices that have less RAM in the first place

So, I made the decision to just support both. The only reason you would have iPad specific images is due to the size, so of course you would need two.

If you just create @2x images, you could write a little shell program using "sips" (or imageMagik) to take these 2x images and make 1x versions (by shrinking).

If no Apple engineer has come forward to date and said categorically that its OK to just do 2x images, and its not in writing, I think that tells you what the official position is.

PS: Suppose Apple were to design a much smaller iPad, one that had a pixel-dense display that was the same pixel width as a non-Retina iPad. And suppose to make it real cheap they used a slower processor and didn't give it lots of memory. Then I guess you'd be better off with both sizes of images, no?

Comment: You pose many good points, I will take them in to consideration. Backwards compatibility is certainly important. In regards to your answer, I suppose the debate begs further questions before one can make that answer: how many images are needed, how often they are called and what are the sizes of those images? etc.. Also, would you not agree that supporting all sizes has the potential to significantly increase the bundle size, also a concern?

Comment: Well, Apple keeps increasing the size allowed for 3G transmission, and the size of the flash keeps increasing, so I'm not so worried about bundle size. RAM size and performance are probably more important. In the end, without some clear indication that a nonstandard way is "better", I prefer to follow the guidelines.